# SQL Plus can't pass parameters to my stored procedure by using Accept

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I've got a problem, I can't pass some character strings from the command line to my stored procedure. I can pass numbers but I can't pass varchar's..

```
accept nr1    char prompt 'Name: ';
accept nr2    char prompt 'Surname: ';
accept nr3    char prompt 'Username: ';
accept nr4    char prompt 'GroupCode: ';

execute CreateUsers('&nr1','&nr2','&nr3','&nr4');
```

I have tried using this

```
accept nr1   prompt 'Name: ';
accept nr2    prompt 'Surname: ';
accept nr3    prompt 'Username: ';
accept nr4    prompt 'GroupCode: ';

declare
    p_name varchar(30) := '&nr1',
    p_surname varchar(30) := '&nr2',
    p_Username varchar(30) := '&nr3',
    p_GroupCode varchar(30) := '&nr4';

begin
execute CreateUsers(p_name,p_surname,p_username,p_GroupCode);

end;
/
```

That stored procedure has `varchar2` parameters and it works with something like

```
execute CreateUsers ('anne','123','annie','DBA');
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks !

EDIT 1
Added error message.[image]

Edit 2
[image]

Edit 3
[image]

Comment: I can't see any problem relating to the handling of the parameters entered in SQL*Plus `accept` statements.  The error in your screenshot is due to two things: (a) you're passing bad data to the stored procedure, and (b) error handling in the stored procedure is insufficient: it is quite probably doing a `SELECT ... INTO ...` and is failing to handle the case that the query returned no data.  Finally, please don't create objects in any of the pre-defined schemas such as `SYSTEM`: instead, create a separate user and use that instead.

Comment: Not really, I do have error handling, passing the same parameters as in the image (1,2,3,4) does the job, doing it with accept doesn't.  I did upload a second image where I've used the second code excerpt. Same parameters passed from the command line do the trick, so there has to be something related to how Accept

Comment: The errors in your second screenshot are complaining about the commas after the variable declarations in the `DECLARE` block.  Each variable declaration in the `DECLARE` block must end with a semicolon.  Replace the commas with semicolons.

Comment: Replaced the commas with semi-colons and that sorted partially the issue, I still encounter a problem at execute CreateUsers area, I think I don't pass the parameters correctly ? Also added a pic

Comment: Remove the `EXECUTE`.  `EXECUTE` isn't a PL/SQL keyword: it's a SQL*Plus shortcut that just wraps the rest of the line in `BEGIN` and `END;`. See your first screenshot.

Comment: Removed it, now it throws a new error, 'Identifier 'createuser' must be declared'. . Now It behaves like it doesn't see the SP.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue, thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problems were in this PL/SQL block:

```
declare
    p_name varchar(30) := '&nr1',
    p_surname varchar(30) := '&nr2',
    p_Username varchar(30) := '&nr3',
    p_GroupCode varchar(30) := '&nr4';

begin
execute CreateUsers(p_name,p_surname,p_username,p_GroupCode);

end;
/
```

The variable declarations in the `declare` section of the block should end with semicolons, not commas, and `execute` should not be used inside a PL/SQL block.

The block should look like the following:

```
declare
    p_name varchar(30) := '&nr1';
    p_surname varchar(30) := '&nr2';
    p_Username varchar(30) := '&nr3';
    p_GroupCode varchar(30) := '&nr4';

begin
  CreateUsers(p_name,p_surname,p_username,p_GroupCode);

end;
/
```